# Can Scrum be used in combination with Step-Wise project planning?

Tags: scrum, software-development, planning, project-management-style

I'm currently reading up on project management and therefore the [Step-Wise framework](https://www.ijecs.in/index.php/ijecs/article/download/2093/1937/), and I was wondering, Can Scrum be used in combination with Step-Wise project planning?

I know that you generally would select a Software Development Life Cycle, like the Iterative model or the Spiral model. But can Scrum be used even though it is a framework?

Couldn't the Activities produced by Step-Wise step 4, be used in the Product Backlog?

*Side Question*
What project planning methods would be better for Scrum?

Comment: @MCW hmm yeah, been told that it is classified as s framework weird it doesn't show on google. Here is a link https://www.ijecs.in/index.php/ijecs/article/download/2093/1937/

Comment: It's not clear to me what the difference between this "Step-Wise framework" and traditional, plan-driven project management methodologies are, even after reading the article.

Comment: http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/9780077122/information_center_view0/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step Wise (Hughes, Cotterell), in common with similar frameworks like PRINCE2, is primarily a description of planning and management activities and has relatively little to say about delivery methods. The 5th Edition of Hughes and Cotterell's book does discuss XP and other agile methods but seemingly without much consideration of how planning game, for example, fits with their Step Wise ideas.

Scrum is very much focussed on methods for teamwork and delivery. One apparent conflict is that Step Wise puts product planning and estimation before allocating resources whereas Scrum favours allocating team(s) first and letting the team(s) own the planning and estimation. With Scrum generally no special frameworks are needed because teams are small, sprints are short and therefore planning is simplified.